# Why is my gallery images overflowing in the testimonial section?

Tags: html, css

I have made a gallery images section using gallery isotope filter but the gallery images are overflowing in the testimonial section. I have used simple HTML and CSS but it is not working. How do I solve this?

This is a image gallery using isotope effect and the lower section is a testimonials sections with a carousal. As far I have tried this is not working. The gallery images are overflowing in the testimonials sections.

```css
#gallery {
  padding: 40px 0;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.portfolio-menu {
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 20px
}

.navigation a {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  border: 1px solid #8cd2ed;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-transition: all .5s ease;
  -moz-transition: all .5s ease;
  -ms-transition: all .5s ease;
  -o-transition: all .5s ease;
  transition: all .5s ease;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.navigation a:hover {
  background: #8cd2ed;
  color: #ffffff;
}

.portfolio-item {
  width: 100%;
}

.portfolio-item .item {
  float: left;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  margin-right: 20px;
}

.harley {
  height: 268px;
  width: 350px;
}

li.active {
  background: #8cd2ed;
  color: #ffffff;
}

#testimonials {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #b1e8ed;
  color: #fff;
}

#testimonials .carousel-item {
  padding: 7% 15%;
}

#testimonials .testimonials-image {
  width: 20%;
  border-radius: 100%;
  margin: 20px;
}

#press {
  background-color: #b1e8ed;
  text-align: center;
  padding-bottom: 3%;
}

.press-logo {
  width: 15%;
  margin: 20px 20px 50px;
}
```

```html
<section id="gallery">
  <div class="container">
    <h1>Gallery</h1>
    <div class="portfolio-menu">
      <div class="navigation">
        <a href="#gallery" data-filter="all" class="button active">All</a>
        <a href="#gallery" data-filter="bike" class="button">Bike</a>
        <a href="#gallery" data-filter="engine" class="button">Engine</a>
        <a href="#gallery" data-filter="custom" class="button">Custom</a>
      </div>

    </div>
    <div class="portfolio-item">
      <div class="item engine">
        <img class="harley" src="img/gallery1.jpg">
      </div>
      <div class="item custom">
        <img class="harley" src="img/gallery2.jpg">
      </div>
      <div class="item custom">
        <img class="harley" src="img/gallery3.jpg">
      </div>
      <div class="item bike">
        <img class="harley" src="img/gallery4.jpg">
      </div>
      <div class="item engine">
        <img class="harley" src="img/gallery5.jpg">
      </div>
      <div class="item custom">
        <img class="harley" src="img/gallery6.jpg">
      </div>
      <div class="item bike">
        <img class="harley" src="img/gallery7.jpg">
      </div>
      <div class="item bike">
        <img class="harley" src="img/gallery8.jpg">
      </div>
      <div class="item engine">
        <img class="harley" src="img/gallery9.jpg">
      </div>
      <div class="item bike">
        <img class="harley" src="img/gallery10.jpg">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>

<section id="testimonials">
  <div id="testimonials-carousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" data-interval="3000" data-pause="hover">
    <div class="carousel-inner">
      <div class="carousel-item active">
        <h2>This is the best bike shop i have ever encountered and love it.</h2>
        <img class="testimonials-image" src="img/testimonial1.jpg" alt="dog-profile">
        <em>Pebbles, New York</em>
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item">
        <h2 class="testimonial-text">Best custom made bikes i have seen so far in the world and trust me i am a bike fanatic.</h2>
        <img class="testimonials-image" src="img/testimonial2.jpg" alt="lady-profile">
        <em>Beverly, Illinois</em>
      </div>
    </div>
    <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#testimonials-carousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
      <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>
    <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#testimonials-carousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
      <span class="carousel-control-next-icon"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a>
  </div>


</section>

<section id="press">
  <img class="press-logo" src="img/techcrunch.png" alt="tc-logo">
  <img class="press-logo" src="img/tnw.png" alt="tnw-logo">
  <img class="press-logo" src="img/bizinsider.png" alt="biz-insider-logo">
  <img class="press-logo" src="img/mashable.png" alt="mashable-logo">

</section>
```

The expected result I should have is different section with the carousal part and different section with the testimonial part.

Comment: You sould create a working snippet so people can help you.

Comment: ya that's true.make working snippet.

Comment: you should remove 100vh from #gallery div

Answer (score 0):

Gallery images overflowing in the Testimonial section due to height. height is applied to `#gallery`.

You should remove height from `#gallery`. Once the height is removing then gallery and testimonial sections display as a different section.

Thanks,